# A question on the Bousso-Polchinski paper

Tags: quantum-field-theory, string-theory, research-level, compactification, cosmological-constant

In this famous paper by Bousso and Polchinski,

[Quantization of Four-form Fluxes and Dynamical Neutralization of the Cosmological Constant](http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0004134)

an example in M-theory compactification is given in section 2.2, page 7.

Since I am new to string theory, I wonder how exactly (2.16)
$$   S= V_72\pi M_{11}^9\int d^4x \sqrt{-g_4}\left(R - {1 \over 2 \cdot 4!} F_4^2\right) + S_{branes}$$
is obtained from (2.12)
$$ S= 2\pi M_{11}^9\int d^{11}x\sqrt{-g_{11}}\left(R-{1 \over 2 \cdot 4!} F_4^2 \right) +S_{{branes}}$$

Is there any assumption made which is not stated in the paper?
Especially, why "eleven dimensional $\bf F_4$ is directly reduced to a four dimensional $\bf F_4$"

Since I am new to string theory, I really want to have a thorough understanding of this work. Detailed explanation is very much appreciated!! Thank you very much!